# How to set a property of an object related to another property of the same object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to set a property of a dart object related to another property of the same object. I have the following code for the button press function:

```
onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
        if (textEditController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
            _sendMessage();
            myMessagesList.add(OwnMessageCard(
                myMessage:
                textEditController.text.trim(),
                isSeen: false,
                deliverIconColor: Colors.grey));
        }
    });
},
```

I want to create condition for `deliverIconColor`. If `isSeen == true` then `deliverIconColor` must be `Colors.blue` and if not then it must be `Colors.grey`.

How can I make such a relation in Flutter?

Comment: If the colors are fixed, then just remove the `deliverIconColor` property. And write condition like `isSeen?Colors.blue:Colors.grey`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use ternary operator

```
onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
        if (textEditController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
            _sendMessage();
            myMessagesList.add(OwnMessageCard(
                myMessage:
                textEditController.text.trim(),
                isSeen: false,
                deliverIconColor: isSeen? Colors.blue : Colors.grey));
        }
    });
},
```